# Is there an easy guide to adding 'animal ears' to a picture (photobashing)?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

Somebody asked me to draw something for them, but I am lazy... so I figured it'd just be easier to find a similar picture online and add the features then toss on an oil filter or whatever in Photoshop.

I have access to the entire Adobe Creative Suite if that's helpful.

Comment: I am not sure its easier, it probably is not on account that you have to ask. For starters you need to learn quote a few techniques. And finding suitable license unencumbered images also take some time.

Comment: @joojaa  eh it was worth a shot. Found an image to edit fairly easily, and I have been meaning to try and learn photoshop... but I probably shouldn't be lazy and just draw it out with my drawingpad (good practice).

Answer (score -2):

you can search the animal ears with transparent background and drag it to your pic. do smooth erasing in the corner of your animal ears pic